# Aplicativos Android / iOs HTML

Tags: php, html, android, css, ios

Preciso desenvolver um aplicativo mobile, gostaria de fazer no estilo do aplicativo da globo, o qual é um site responsivo que é exibido, que programa devo usar para desenvolver em html e ser compilado para as plataformas?

Comment: Tente o Phonegap, atende bem as suas necessidades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você tem diversas formas de trabalhar com isso.
Pode usar o IONIC (Phonegap), tem o Intel XDK entre outras ferramentas.

Você também pode fazer um site responsivo, e encapsular dentro de uma webview no android, ios ou windows phone.

Comment: Só uma ressalva: O Ionic e o Phonegap são coisas diferentes. Vide [explicação](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/4cah35/what_is_the_difference_between_phonegap_and_ionic/)

Comment: eu gostaria dessa ultima opção, porem nao sei como encapsular em uma webview, existe algum programa para isso?

Comment: você ja tem o site pronto? se tiver basta criar um projeto no android studio.
Use o componente WebView e passa a Url do seu site.
Para funcionar libere acesso a internet no android manifest.
Caso não conheça programação mobile, vai ter que dar uma estuda basica para gerar os apps.

Comment: Sim, é o habitamais.com, apenas irei desenvolver uma pagina especifica para o app, você poderia me indicar tópicos para eu estudar? é bem simples o que quero fazer porém nunca tive experiencia com mobile

Comment: Vai ser multiplataforma ou apenas android?